# R: Getting more informative error messages in R

Tags: r, debugging, metaprogramming, callstack, function-call

I am still not very good at using R’s standard debugging tools, and I often find that neither the error nor the traceback tell me enough to figure out what is going on. I would like to change R’s default behavior on error to provide more information.

Specifically, I would always like the `call`, including the `formals`, the expression assigned to each formal (the default expression if the default is the expression assigned), and the value of each of the argument expressions as evaluated in place, all returned in a format that makes it unambiguous which expression has been matched to which formal and which values go with which expression. Since the values might be large or of unexpected or evanescent type, I’d like them to be returned in a format, such as a `str()`, that makes intelligent choices about truncation and correctly identifies promises and other object types that tend to evaluate themselves into something else before you see them.

And finally, I’d like all these things, together with the `return` value of each `call`, for every function on the call stack from the error back to (and including) some piece of code that I wrote. It seems to me that the natural structure would be a single R object, a `list` of lists, one list per `call` (perhaps tidied, `broom`-like, into a tibble with some list columns) that I could single-step through in the obvious way.

I apologize if I have described some standard R debugging tool that I just haven't learned how to use properly yet. Is this even possible? If it is, could it be implemented via R's available error handlers, or would it need some  package-scale coding project?

I would most prefer a solution that changes the default error response to this, but if that is impracticable, I'd accept a solution that requires that I rerun a code chunk with a wrapper or something similar.

Comment: Have you had a look at this https://adv-r.hadley.nz/conditions.html#custom-conditions?

Comment: Thanks @prosoitos !  I've read this several times, and thought about how best to use it. I don't think it provides much assistance in the most common case where I need more help: where the error is three to 12 steps up the call stack, & I didn't write most of the intervening code. Unless I am missing something, in order to get custom error handling in that function, I'd have to write, not only a custom version of the final function, but a custom version of the calling function to to call the custom function, and so forth for all the intervening functions. This seems impractical to me.

Comment: I wasn't sure how helpful it would be. Just wanted to bring it up in case... since you were not having much luck with your question. Sorry I can't help more!

Comment: Maybe this will give you a good start to implement what you need: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tryCatchLog/versions/1.0.2/topics/get.pretty.call.stack

Comment: @andrewH Can you provide a code example in support of your question. I want to see the code problem to hopefully be able to map back with a detailed answer.

Comment: @Technophobe01, this was a marvel of bad planning on my part. I am facing a  stack of pre-holiday deadlines that have me working round the clock, and I should not have posted my bounty until I was free to respond to persons like you. I will respond, but it may not be until after Christmas.